# React: Action on variable change

Tags: html, css, reactjs

is there a way how to call method on variable change(state).
How to get List which components changed ?

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {

    const {ID} = this.state
        if (this.ID !== this.previousID || this.cmbID !== this.previoudcmbID) {
            if(this.ID !== undefined && this.cmbID !== undefined)
            {
                this.reload3();

            //  console.log(this.prevProps)
                console.log(this.state.settings[0])
                console.log(this.prevState.settings[0])

            }



    }
    this.prevState = this.state;
}
```

Comment: There isn't an inbuilt React functionality to specifically list which parts of the state/props changed in an update (as far as I know), but there are lifecycle methods with access to both previous and current state/props so you can use that to determine the difference, if you want to know what changed. Then call a function accordingly.

Comment: @Jayce444 I am trying to do that with that method. But i have problem if i call "console.log(this.state)" i get clean variables. 2. do you know how to do that with any module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally solved

```
componentDidUpdate(PrevProps, prevState){
if(this.state.cmbID !== prevState.cmbID){

    this.reload2()
}   
if(this.state.ID !== prevState.ID){

    this.reload3()
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using this.setState({value: "newValue"}) you can use its other form which is

this.setState({}, callback) where callback will be having new values after state updated and you can handle it somehow there in more elegant way.
Pseudo code below

```
<div onClick={this.handler} />
handler = () => this.setState({value: "newValue}, () => console.log(this.state.value))
```

Comment: Thanks, but i am trying to do that without action(onClick).

Answer (score 1):

You need not maintain a `prevState`, if the variable that needs to be monitored is either in state or props, you can just make use of `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook to do the same

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {

        const {ID, cmbID} = this.state
        const {ID: prevId, cmbID: prevCmbId} = prevState;
        if (ID !== prevId || cmbID !== prevCmbId) {
            if(typeof ID !== 'undefined' && typeof cmbID !== 'undefined')
            {
                this.reload3();

                console.log(prevProps)
                console.log(this.state.settings[0])
                console.log(prevState.settings[0])

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont see any filled variable if i call prevProps, Props, prevState, State. Only if i call variable directly by this.ID